# Angular casting http get response but not nested property

Tags: json, angular, http, casting, client

I am returning a list of products of type **ListProd** in my Spring Boot controller, and such object has a nested property of type `List<Product>` ... something like this:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
      int codProdct;
      String dsc;
      
      public Product(){};
      
      // plus getters and setters (omitted for simplicity)
}

public class ListProd implements Serializable {
      int codList;
      List<Product> products;

      public ListProd(){};

      // also here getters and setters
}
```

and in my angular project I have the next analogoust entities:

```
export class Product {
    public codProduct:number;
    public dsc:string;

    constructor(){ 
           codProduct=null;   //just for completness
           dsc='';
    }
}

export class ListProd {
    public codList:number;
    public products:Product[];
    
    constructor(){
        this.codList=null;   //just for completness
        this.products=null;
    }
}
```

I'm sending a ListProd object through my  Spring controller and Angular gets such an object correctly and assigns the type also correctly:

```
return this.http.get<ListProd>(this.apiUrl + "/getListProds", httpOptions);
```

but ... it is only casting correctly the parent object, when I check the type of the 'products' object (which is recived correctly, only untyped) y get type: **Object**

I tried to make it a Products[] in my ListProd class in java, but i get the same result. I don't know much about the 'magic' Angular does to assign those types properly, am I missing something important here? Is there a chance to force the casting on the Angular side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `ListProd` is supposed to hold array of `Product[]` there is a typo here.

```
 public products:Product[];
```

Not knowing full extent why you use class over an interface I would advise you also to go over this. Maybe there is a reason but for being able to strong type simple interface would be better. https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-class-vs-interface

Comment: yes, it was a typo... already corrected. Well, I know interfaces work better, but I can't see why this way  it fails...